# How to handle redirect for login_required in htmx partial view?

Tags: django, htmx

I have two views.

```py
class IndexView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'index.html'

@require_POST
@login_required
def partial_view(request):
    return render(request, 'partials/stuff.html')
```

I want the index page to be "public" but if user takes action (which triggers partial view), they should be redirected to `LOGIN_URL`, if not logged in.

The problem is that my partial view will return the entire `LOGIN_URL` page. So there's a page within a page now.

Is it possible to redirect the "parent" page when using partial views?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't manage to make "post-login redirection" work but my solution is good enough for my needs.

```py
from django.contrib.auth import REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required as django_login_required
from django.http import HttpResponse
from functools import wraps

from django.shortcuts import resolve_url


def login_required(function=None, login_url=None, redirect_field_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME):
    @wraps(function)
    def wrapper(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated and request.htmx:
            resolved_login_url = resolve_url(login_url or settings.LOGIN_URL)
            return HttpResponse(status=204, headers={'HX-Redirect': resolved_login_url})
        return django_login_required(
            function=function,
            login_url=login_url,
            redirect_field_name=redirect_field_name
        )(request, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```